# How can I apply a colortable to my grayscale 8 bit image and convert it correctly in Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-processing

I would like to convert my grayscale_8 QImage to an Indexed_8 with a colortable. I found have found and tested functions that generate a colormap ([MATLAB jet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mycTm.png)) accurately -- here is my code:

```
for (double i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {

    double hi = 255;
    double lo = 0;
    double r = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 3.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;
    double g = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 2.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;
    double b = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 1.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;


    CP->colortable.append(qRgb(r < lo ? lo : r > hi ? hi : r, g < lo ? lo : g > hi ? hi : g, b < lo ? lo : b > hi ? hi : b));


}
```

The r,g,b doubles represent MATLAB's jet colormap, given inputs from 0 to 255 and outputs within the range (0,255). The ternary operators are equivalent to std::clamp, and limit values to between 0 and 255.

Then I convert the image as follows:

```
q = QImage((uchar*)p->GetBuffer(), p->GetWidth(), p->GetHeight(), QImage::Format_Grayscale8);


QImage c = q.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8, colortable);

ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(c));
```

You can see there is no red in this image

[image]

despite the fact that I know the value in the cyan section has pixel values of 255. It would appear that blue is added back in place of red. Is this a simple formatting error?

Here is what the MATLAB jet colormap looks like normalized

[image]

and

here is what my image should look like

[image].

Comment: please upload the original image data

Comment: whether it should be BGR and blue first and last one is red

Comment: you can use ```qBound(minValue, myValue, maxValue)``` instead of those  ternary operators

Comment: I checked your color table generation. IMHO, this looks reasonable. [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1588e360d73ece15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I checked whether OP's exposed algorithm for the color table provides reasonable values. For this, I wrote a small sample around the exposed code on [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1588e360d73ece15) and checked generated values by eyes. The output looks reasonable (according to the presented snapshot from MatLab) – I assume that's not the issue.

Next I investigated into

```
q = QImage((uchar*)p->GetBuffer(), p->GetWidth(), p->GetHeight(), QImage::Format_Grayscale8);


QImage c = q.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8, colortable);

ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(c));
```

The doc. of the used function [**QImage::convertToFormat()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat-2):

> ### QImage QImage::convertToFormat(QImage::Format format, const QVector &colorTable, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor) const
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Returns a copy of the image converted to the given format, using the specified colorTable.
>
> Conversion from RGB formats to indexed formats is a slow operation and will use a straightforward nearest color approach, with no dithering.

was no real help. The last sentence with the *straightforward nearest color approach* made me suspicious somehow.

So, I had some doubts whether it just re-uses the data values as indexes into the color table. But that's what OP actually intends to do.

Actually, I want something like a “reinterprete-cast” of the image.

So, I came up with this approach:

1. create a `QImage` with width and height of original image, and `QImage::Format_Indexed8`
2. set color table of this image as proposed by OP
3. copy the data of original image into this image.

Sample `testQImageGrayToRGB.cc`:

```
#include <vector>

#include <QtWidgets>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

QImage buildSample(const int w = 256, const int h = 32)
{
  QImage qImg(w, h, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
  const int bpl = qImg.bytesPerLine();
  for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
    uchar *row = qImg.bits() + y * bpl;
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
      row[x] = (uchar)(x * 255 / (w - 1));
    }
  }
  return qImg;
}

const QVector<QRgb> makeColorTable()
{
  QVector<QRgb> qColTbl;
  const double hi = 255;
  const double lo = 0;
  for (double i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    double r = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 3.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;
    double g = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 2.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;
    double b = -4.0 * std::abs(i - 255.0 * 1.0 / 4) + 255.0 * 3.0 / 2;
    qColTbl.append(
      qRgb(
        r < lo ? lo : r > hi ? hi : r,
        g < lo ? lo : g > hi ? hi : g,
        b < lo ? lo : b > hi ? hi : b));
  }
  return qColTbl;
}

QImage colorize(const QImage &qImg, const QVector<QRgb> &qColTbl)
{
  const int w = qImg.width(), h = qImg.height();
  QImage qImgDst(w, h, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
  qImgDst.setColorTable(qColTbl);
  const int bpl = qImg.bytesPerLine();
  const int bplDst = qImgDst.bytesPerLine();
  for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
    const uchar *row = qImg.bits() + y * bpl;
    uchar *rowDst = qImgDst.bits() + y * bplDst;
    std::copy(row, row + w, rowDst);
  }
  return qImgDst;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build contents
  const QImage qImgGray = buildSample();
  const QVector<QRgb> qColTbl = makeColorTable();
  const QImage qImgColorOP
    = qImgGray.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8, qColTbl);
  const QImage qImgColorDS
    = colorize(qImgGray, qColTbl);
  // build some GUI
  QWidget win;
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QLabel qLblGray(
    QString::fromUtf8("QImage Source: (QImage::Format_Grayscale8)"));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblGray);
  QLabel qLblImgGray;
  qLblImgGray.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImgGray));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblImgGray);
  QLabel qLblColorOP(
    QString::fromUtf8("QImage Colorized: (Attempt of OP)"));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblColorOP);
  QLabel qLblImgColorOP;
  qLblImgColorOP.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImgColorOP));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblImgColorOP);
  QLabel qLblColorDS(
    QString::fromUtf8("QImage Colorized: (Attempt of DS)"));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblColorDS);
  QLabel qLblImgColorDS;
  qLblImgColorDS.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImgColorDS));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblImgColorDS);
  win.setLayout(&qVBox);
  win.show();
  // exec. application
  return app.exec();
}
```

A minimal Qt-Project file `testQImageGrayToRGB.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQImageGrayToRGB.cc

QT += widgets
```

Output (VisualStudio 2013, Qt 5.9.2):

[image: testQImageGrayToRGB.exe (built with VS 2013)]

Oops. The middle image (which should resemble the approach of OP) looks a bit different than expected from OPs sample.

However, the bottom image achieved with my “reinterprete-cast” approach does look like expected.

Just for fun, I built the sample again in [**cygwin64**](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQImageGrayToRGB.pro

$ make && ./testQImageGrayToRGB 
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQImageGrayToRGB.o testQImageGrayToRGB.cc
g++  -o testQImageGrayToRGB.exe testQImageGrayToRGB.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

Output (cygwin64, g++ (GCC) 7.4.0, Qt 5.9.4):

[image: testQImageGrayToRGB.exe (built with g++ in cygwin)]

**Aha!** Now, the colors of middle image resembles what OP described.

---

**Note:**

Actually, graylevel and indexed image could share the same data. This would make the row-for-row copy obsolete. However, the life-times of the `QImage` owning the data and the `QImage` sharing the data have to be considered carefully in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough analysis and response. I have implemented your “colorize” function and it works great. Interesting you see the same weird result from my method!

Comment: @JoeNatal Actually, I was more surprised that I got distinct results in VS and cygwin/gcc with your approach. This looks like in your case the `convertToFormat()` doesn't seem to have a defined behavior. IMHO, this could have been mentioned in the doc... ;-) (Aside of this, I still consider the Qt doc. as one of the best and most encompassing I've ever seen.)