# QImage false coloring with Format Indexed8

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qimage

I'm currently having som trouble with false-coloring a QImage with a colormap I generate. I have stripped down the code to some basic steps (usually distributed over multiple classes).

I can reproduce the problem with this code:

```
    //fill color table
    QVector< QRgb > colors;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        double fac = (double(i) / 255.) * 0.8;
        QColor color = QColor::fromHslF(fac, 0.95, 0.5);
        colors.push_front(color.rgba());
    }

    //load original
    QImage origImg;
    origImg.load("lena.jpg");
    QImage::Format f = origImg.format(); //outputs Format_Grayscale8 (24)
    origImg.save("out1.jpg");

    //convert to pixmap
    QPixmap pixmap;
    pixmap.convertFromImage(origImg);

    //convert back to Image
    QImage tmp = pixmap.toImage();
    tmp.save("out2.jpg");

    //make false color version
    QImage fc = QImage(tmp.bits(), tmp.width(), tmp.height(), QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    fc.setColorTable(colors);

    //save false color version
    fc.save("fc.jpg");
```

My temporary results out1.jpg and out2.jpg look fine (copies of the original) but the final result is broken. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

original image:

[image: original image]

output for fc.jpg

[image: output for fc.jpg]

Comment: FYI: [SO: How can I apply a colortable to my grayscale 8 bit image and convert it correctly in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58672586/7478597) (Notably, the `colorize()` function in my sample code might be of help.)

Comment: Your last image looks like the R, G, B, A bytes have been stored "literally" into your image and are then interpreted byte for byte as index values. The "grid" and the "ghost" appearance of parts of the original image let me think this.

Comment: In the raster Qt backend (that you're using), `QPixmap` is just a wrapper around `QImage`, There's no point to using `QPixmap`, unless it's required by some existing API, in which case it'd be required for read-only access anyway, and you can "convert" the image to a pixmap where needed. The "conversion" is cheap.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica it is not a fresh implementation but correction of this behaviour in a larger-scale software. Would be smarter to use QImage directly and do the conversion when rendering as QPixmap loses the information to convert back. AFAIK it can't apply the inverse of the color table and so the gray information is lost on the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
QImage tmp = pixmap.toImage();
```

to

```
QImage tmp = pixmap.toImage().convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

The QPixmap stores the image as RGB, so when you convert from QPixmap to QImage the format will be 32 bpp (`Format_RGB32`). Converting back to `Format_Grayscale8`, will give you the expected 8 bpp grayscale format.